# Does Multisim have coaxial cable? What simulation application can I use that has coaxial cable?

Tags: simulation, cables, multisim, coaxial

I want to use coaxial cable in a simulation.

Is it available in Multisim or another simulation program?

Comment: Any simulator will be able to use the mid-frequency approximation of a coaxial cable as an LC ladder. I couldn't tell you if yours in particular can do the high-frequency distributed-element model.

Answer (score 1):

Micro-Cap has transmission line as component type. It can be as well ideal or lossy. The program has been a few years freeware. The developer kept it as his own business project (=Spectrum Software) nearly 40 years, but finally released it. The last version (=12) feels somehow odd - not claiming it's bad -  I use v10 which looks solid as rock.

Check these:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-Cap

http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm

BTW many of us have suggested or used Micro-Cap simulations in this site. An example: [Parallel transmision lines reflection at the source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559282/parallel-transmision-lines-reflection-at-the-source)

**About NI Multisim**: National Instruments have in their support some data which suggests that there's also model for transmission line and so there's no need to build it as a big bunch of LRC elements.

https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/375482B-01/multisim/lossytransmissionline/

That model probably does the same as what's in Micro-Cap - so it can present as well coaxial cable or other transmission lines where 2 coductors are in parallel. I have not tried how it works in Multisim.